# How to show the Logged Messages window in Xcode

Tags: cocoa, arrays, xcode, logging

I'm a very new Cocoa user and running into all sorts of problems...

I'm trying to get the content of an Array and found this code to do this.

> NSLog(@"array : %@",collection);

The problem is, I'm not getting any console or tracer window that shows this 'echo'

Is there another command I should use, i've tried opening all windows but I don't see the message that should show. I know the function that this call is in is executed, so the reference is right.

Thanks and sorry for these beginner questions... Using stackoverflow is way faster than reading through all the documentation apple has regarding the subject.

Comment: the 'collection' array is of a type 'NSMutableArray'

Comment: thanks all... I've NEVER been on a forum that answers as quickly as this site... it's absolutely brilliant!

Comment: I like to think we're feeding a future expert system.

Comment: I am having this problem with XCode 3.2.3 (I am an experienced developer)..  Only SOME of my printf's and NSLogs are showing up in the console.  Any ideas?

Comment: OMG!  Never mind.  stray #ifndef was setting a variable that turned logging off!  I *hate* that!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**Update for 2023 :** It's Command + Shift + C

**Old answer** : It's shift + cmd + R. Or go to View -> Debug Area -> Activate Console

Comment: Thanks, any way to keep it open? It closes every time I stop running. And it doesn't show any logs for me

Comment: Does it still work in XCode 12? It looks to me to do something else. Any idea what? And by default it seems now to be Shift Cmd C to show console

Comment: To finish the cycle: It is now Command + Shift + C (but that shortcut shows when you go to the suggested menu item)

Comment: @Andy A: Could you update your answer?

Answer (score 9):

In Xcode 12, go to View > Debug Area > Activate Console

[image]

Answer (score 7):

When Xcode runs your project, the editor changes to show a little black button with the letters "GDB" in it. Click on that to see the Debugger which has the console in it.

Good luck!

Oh, and I would read Apple's documentation. It's not that bad.

Comment: I don't see any black button or GDP

Answer (score 7):

From the 'Run' menu, choose 'Console' - keyboard shortcut is Shift-Cmd-R.

Comment: Shift-Cmd-R just does a build. Doesn't show any console

Answer (score 3):

In the Xcode menu hit **Run** - **Console**. This is where NSLog / print / printf etc statements output.

The key command is **Command + Shift + R**.

The cocoa **toString()** method is called **description** as well.

```
NSLog(@"array : %@",collection);
```

Will execute

```
NSLog(@"array : %@",[collection description]);
```

Which will then call description on each of the collections elements.

Comment: I don't have a Run menu

Comment: Curtis, this answer is 11 years out of date.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to see it every time you run your application select the "Debugging" tab from the preferences window and change the box that says "On Start" to "Show Console". 
Additionally i like to check the "Auto Clear Debug Console" checkbox which will clear out the text of the output on starting your application.