# Where can one view the result of a printf function call in xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode4

Where can one view the result of a printf function call in xcode? i.e. where is the console/output window....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Cmd+Shift+R` opens Console where you see your program's output (like `NSLog(@"text %@", str)`) and errors

Answer (score 0):

`View | Show Debug Area` or click the middle icon in the view toolbar in the top right of the window.

Answer (score 0):

1) I would use NSLog for this, not printf.

2) "When XCode runs your project, the editor changes to show a little black button with the letters "GDB" in it. Click on that to see the Debugger which has the console in it."
from: [How to show the Logged Messages window in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483493/how-to-show-the-logged-messages-window-in-xcode)