# iOS application ExternalHosts

Tags: ios, cordova

I'm developing an app using phonegap/cordova (1.7.0), I can't figure out how to make my application work with a less restrictive option than `*`. If I try setting `www.mywebservicedomain.com` or `*.mywebservicedomain.com` it can't retrieve data anymore. I see many questions about this and the general answer is to just set `*`. I'd like to understand how to be more restrictive, if it is possible.

Thank you in advance for your efforts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is indeed possible. But be aware that redirects on the servers may lead to connections to different domains which you also have to specifiy. Luckily those restricted accesses appear in the debug log in xcode. Run the project on the simulator or the device from within xcode and then you will see which requests to which servers got blocked.

In the cordova.plist it should look like this:

```
<key>ExternalHosts</key>
<array>
    <string>*.googleapis.com</string>
    <string>*.gstatic.com</string>
</array>
```

I use Google maps in my project which uses the described redirect. Thus I had to add the `gstatic` although my requests point to `maps.googleapis.com` originally (I use cordova 1.7).

Comment: Thank you. For xcode newbs like me, here is how to see debug log messages: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/483493/how-to-show-the-logged-messages-window-in-xcode